# Collapsible lists using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a collapsible list implemented using HTML and CSS. The list works properly, but I need a little modification.

Whenever I click an item in the list it expands. But as I click on another item in the same list, the previously expanded element gets collapsed while the clicked one gets expanded.

Please help me to apply the behavior that makes it possible to expand multiple list items at the same time.

I want it to be done in HTML and CSS only.

Here is the implementation I currently have. CSS styles:

```css
.row { vertical-align: top; height: auto !important; }
list { display: none; }
.show { display: none; }
.hide:target + .show { display: inline; }
.hide:target { display: none; }
.hide:target ~ .list { display:inline; }
@media print { .hide, .show { display: none; } }
```

And the HTML markup:

```html
<div class="row">
  <a href="#hide1" class="hide" id="hide1">Expand</a>
  <a href="#show1" class="show" id="show1">Collapse</a>
  <div class="list">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 125):

### If you use a modern browser, you can just use HTML5 like this:

```html
<details>
  <summary>See More</summary>
  This text will be hidden if your browser supports it.
</details>
```

One can find more information about [`<details>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) HTML element, including other examples, on MDN.

Comment: See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_details.asp for more information.

Comment: A good answer, yet IE/EDGE IIRC has no support for it yet, so... not always acceptable.

Comment: @haldagan answer says: if you use Modern browser

Comment: Let's say if you would have a list nested inside another list: Can you use this for several branches? Is it good practice or should another option be more tidy code-wise?

Comment: @nilon I just tried it and you can nest lists, but you don't get any kind of indention by default.

Comment: @nilon, may be you can use some CSS to add some indentation for the nested lists.

Answer (score 20):

Pure HTML & CSS
A **checkbox** and its `:checked` state sounds like a perfect match for your case:

```css
[id^="togList"],                        /* HIDE CHECKBOX */
[id^="togList"] ~ .list,                /* HIDE LIST */
[id^="togList"] + label  span + span,   /* HIDE "Collapse" */
[id^="togList"]:checked + label span{   /* HIDE "Expand" (IF CHECKED) */
  display:none;
}
[id^="togList"]:checked + label span + span{
  display:inline-block;                 /* SHOW "Collapse" (IF CHECKED) */
}
[id^="togList"]:checked ~ .list{
  display:block;                        /* SHOW LIST (IF CHECKED) */
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <input id="togList1" type="checkbox">
  <label for="togList1">
    <span>Expand</span>
    <span>Collapse</span>
  </label>
  <div class="list">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help,but if we could use an arrow button instead of the checkbox it will fit my requirements....

Answer (score 4):

Based on the answers above, just created a single HTML with CSS and JS embedded for this kind of task.
[GitHub repo](https://github.com/Leedehai/expandable-tree-list), the link will stay valid as I have no plan to remove it.