# Anyway to get HTML5 Interactive Elements to work in IE 11?

Tags: javascript, css, html, internet-explorer-11

I am working on a `SharePoint` site for my company. Most of the formatting work I am doing in `HTML`. One of the things that I was having trouble accomplishing was building collapsible lists via only `HTML`. I am trying to avoid `JS` and altering any `CSS`as my previous attempts were disastrous. Finally today I discovered this [HTML5 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977965/collapsible-lists-using-html-and-css). It works beautifully... in Chrome. No bueno in `IE 11` or `Edge` though. After researching [incompatibilities across browsers](https://html5test.com/results/desktop.html), it appears that (the one function I actually need) is not supported by `IE 11` or `Edge`. The problem with this is that employees here mostly use `IE 11` or `Edge`. Is there a simple way to force `IE 11` to use the Interactive Elements `details` and `summary`? My code is below.

```
<h3>Documents</h3>
<details><summary><img class="ms-asset-icon ms-rtePosition-4" src="Folder.gif" alt=""/>Policies and Notices<br/></summary>
<p style="text-indent: 5em;">
  <a href="FilePath"> 
     <img class="ms-asset-icon ms-rtePosition-4" src="FilePath.png" alt=""/>Policy Guide.pdf</a><br/></p>
<p style="text-indent: 5em;">
  <a href="FilePath"> 
     <img class="ms-asset-icon ms-rtePosition-4" src="FilePath.png" alt=""/>Firm Holidays.doc</a><br/></p>
<p style="text-indent: 5em;">
  <a href="FilePath"> 
     <img class="ms-asset-icon ms-rtePosition-4" src="FilePath.png" alt=""/>Evacuation Procedures.doc</a><br/></p>
<p style="text-indent: 5em;">
  <a href="FilePath"> 
     <img class="ms-asset-icon ms-rtePosition-4" src="FilePath.png" alt=""/>Inclement Weather Policy.doc</a><br/></p></details>
```

Comment: `details p{display:none} details:hover p{display:block}` should be remedy for IE / Edge

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. That doesn't look like `HTML`, more like `CSS` or `JS`.

Comment: Yes, sure, this is CSS. Summary tag is not supported by IE / Edge.